# If else command

Tags: strings, renewcommand

Why is the below code not working? I tried also `renewcommand` instead of `def`. The counter/`\setcounter` does not provide the value of the width which is why I stopped using it. Any idea of how to fix this? I guess that the variable `\mylen` is a string somehow or something like this.

```
        \def\maxim{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mylen{width("some te432xt")}
        \ifnum \maxim>\mylen {} \else \def\maxim{\mylen}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\mylen{width("Th2432")}
        \ifnum \maxim>\mylen {} \else \def\maxim{\mylen}
```

The error is (twice repeated):

> Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \ifnum \maxim`

Comment: `\ifnum` can't compare floats, use `\ifdim\maxim pt>\mylen pt` instead. Why do you use `\pgfmathsetmacro` for this task? Instead you could just use `\newsavebox\mybox\newlength\maxim` and in your code `\maxim=0pt\sbox\mybox{some te432xt}\ifdim\maxim<\wd\mybox\maxim=\wd\mybox\fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of your problem was given in the comment above. I recommend to stay with TeX primitives, so don't use LaTeX macro `\sbox` but primitive `\setbox`. Whole calculation can be done with dimens and if you want do have the result without `pt` then you can remove it by `\nopt` defined in the code below:

```
\def\maxim{0pt}
\setbox0=\hbox{{some te432x}}
\ifdim \maxim<\wd0 \edef\maxim{\the\wd0}\fi
\setbox0=\hbox{{Th2432}}
\ifdim \maxim<\wd0 \edef\maxim{\the\wd0}\fi

\expandafter\def \expandafter\nopt \expandafter#\detokenize{1pt}{#1}
\edef\maxim {\expandafter\nopt\maxim}

result: \maxim
```